# Getting NPM 407 error while installing jquery, in VPN

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy, vpn

I am trying to install jquery using npm in my project, but it is giving this error : `npm ERR! 407 Proxy Authentication Required - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/jquery`. On Googling I found out that we have to set proxy settings using commands such as `npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:proxyport`  but I am using a VPN network, and in proxy settings it shows `*Some properties are hidden or managed by your organization` How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Correct proxy setting:

HOME:File .npmrc

```
Mac:
/Users/user_name/.npmrc
Window:
C:\Users\user_name\.npmrc
```

Add proxy with username and password

```
proxy=http://username:password@proxy_url:8080
http-proxy=http://username:password@proxy_url:8080
https-proxy=http://username:password@proxy_url:8080
```

**Note:** If your password contains special char, replace with encoded value. Like @ will be %40

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I am not being able to find my proxy URL, as I am using VPN in wireless wifi router, there is nothing present at IE Browser -> Internet Options -> Connections tab -> LAN Settings. where usually I might find proxy settings.

Comment: yes!. there will one url, just open and check ur proxy links. I m not working on windows for long time. So I could not remember
 https://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-set-your-proxy-settings-in-windows-8.1/